# How can I make a countdown timer with start button counting back from the seconds we previously add in input? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I am just looking for a very simple solution. I have checked several countdown timers but not sure how to make this one.

I only need the timer to count back from seconds that can be added in an input field.

Comment: I believe you want to get the value of an input to set a countdown

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var output = document.querySelector("p");
var button = document.querySelector("button");


button.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    var seconds = input.value;
    output.innerHTML = seconds;
    var counter = window.setInterval(function(){
      seconds = seconds - 1;
      if(seconds <= 0){
        window.clearInterval(counter);
      }
      output.innerHTML = seconds;
    }, seconds*1000);
});
```

```html
<label for=num>Enter No of Seconds </label><input type=number id=num></input>
<button>start</button>
<p>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Ronnie for your help! This is a nice and easy code. However, there is a problem with the seconds. The timer is very slow and it is supposed to count back faster.